# Angular 2+ ReactiveForm Custom Validation Function Not Triggered

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I'm building my `FormGroup` in the following manner:

```js
this.datesGroup = this.fb.group({
  arrivalDate: [null, Validators.required],
  departureDate: [null, Validators.required]
}, (fg: FormGroup) => {
  console.log('validate');
  return moment.unix(fg.value.departureDate.epoc).diff(moment.unix(fg.value.arrivalDate.epoc)) > 0 ?
    null : {
      'departureBeforeArrival': true
    };
});
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  dates: this.datesGroup,
  accommodation: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

But the validation arrow function above is never triggered; the console never logs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormBuilder.group` method takes 2 parameters:

```
group(controlsConfig: {
        [key: string]: any;
    }, extra?: {
        [key: string]: any;
    } | null): FormGroup;
```

where `extra` can be `object` with property `validator` and/or `asyncValidator`.

So i would change your code to this:

```
this.datesGroup = this.fb.group({
  arrivalDate: [null, Validators.required],
  departureDate: [null, Validators.required]
}, {
  validator: (fg: FormGroup) => {
    console.log('validate');
    return 1 > 0 ?
      null : {
        'departureBeforeArrival': true
      };
  }
});
```

Live example could be found here https://plnkr.co/edit/BcExweMVcVxy1yKhwmJp?p=preview

Comment: +1 :). I think the  [**docs**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#overview) could be better explaining what this "extra" means, as it does for `FormControl` and `FormArray`. (I know it's explained well in `FormGroup`, but it should be also in `FormBuilder`).